# Should I Implement RAID level 1 for repeated HDD Crash

Tags: hard-drive, raid, crash

My Seagate GoFlex 1TB HDD crashed, and is now clicking. Should I implement RAID level 1 to avoid this happening again. Also are portable HDD's Like Goflex capable of supporting RAID level 1.

If this is possible, how can I set it up?

Comment: Operating systerm or RAID hardware might help.  Also, not sure what "clocking" means.  More detailed inforamtion may avoid having the question closed.

Comment: It seems to me that if the drive is going flaky you should just replace it.  After all, you'd have to spend the money on a second drive to implement RAID.

Comment: Replace the drive immediately.

Comment: i'll get the drive replaced as soon as i get the data out from it, all i'm trying is to find a solution for such a disk, like some software that might make it possible to read data from it.

Answer (score 1):

RAID 1 should be used as a prevention, and a safeguard, rather than a solution to an existing problem.

As for your particular drive, it is a very ineffective treatment to use any form of disk-pairing across drives with expected portability. You would be better off backing up and being mindful the drive could fail, or use some form of offsite storage like Dropbox, or Google Drive to name a few.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, But I use My Portable Disk Just Like an Fixed Disk, Thats why I did Thought of RAID 1, also I would like to implement it on the replaced disk that i'll get from Seagate and with a New Seagate 1 TB HDD that I'll buy, but My Question is "IS THESE PORTABLE HDD's SUPPORT RAID 1 ? " OR NOT?